# On table body clone Multiselect's values aren't cloning in it

Tags: php, html, jquery

```
if($("#hide_show_option_list_"+ele_no).html()!='')
                {        
                    $("#options_table").html("");
                    $("#options_table").html($("#hide_show_option_list_"+ele_no+" tbody").clone());
                    
                }
```

In this code, I am cloning the table body on another table. In the parent table, I have multi select dropdown. Before cloning getting multi-select dropdown's value but after cloning in table cloned table just shows selected values in multi-select but not getting values by val() on the multi-select dropdown of the cloned table.

Comment: We need to see more more code, what `.val()` are you not able to get? Also watch out for duplicated ids, maybe that is the problems

Comment: I think you may need to change the id of the elements you are cloning... that's usually a problem in the dom both because elements with the same ids are not valid but more concretely because the selectors needed to address them will just fail. But it would help if you included your table html

Comment: What if you change clone into html? But maybe first check if the content you try to fetch is really has content